# Multiple domains all incorrectly point to the same VirtualHost with Django WSGI

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, virtualhost

I'm running Django using wsgi. I have two domains and one sub domain pointing to three seperate apache2 virtual hosts. For some (probably very obvious) reason each domain is landing to the same site (the first one that was put online using a2ensite). My configuration is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.one.com/
   ServerAlias one.com
   ServerAdmin andy@one.com

   DocumentRoot /srv/www/one.com/public_html

   <Directory /srv/www/one.com/application>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

   WSGIDaemonProcess one.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
   WSGIProcessGroup one.com
   WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/one/application/apache/one.wsgi

   Alias /robots.txt /srv/www/one.com/public_html/robots.txt
   Alias /favicon.ico /srv/www/one.com/public_html/favicon.ico
   Alias /media /srv/www/one.com/public_html/media
   Alias /static /srv/www/one.com/public_html/static

   ErrorLog /srv/www/one.com/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /srv/www/one.com/logs/access.log combined   

</VirtualHost>
```

////// /// one.wsgi //////////

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/srv/www/one.com/application')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

//////////////////

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName dev.one.co.uk/
   ServerAlias www.dev.one.co.uk/
   ServerAdmin andy@one.com

   DocumentRoot /srv/www/dev.one.com/public_html


   <Directory /srv/www/dev.one.com/application>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

   WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/dev.one.com/application/apache/devone.wsgi

   Alias /robots.txt /srv/www/dev.one.com/public_html/robots.txt
   Alias /favicon.ico /srv/www/dev.one.com/public_html/favicon.ico
   Alias /media /srv/www/dev.one.com/public_html/media
   Alias /static /srv/www/dev.one.com/public_html/static

   ErrorLog /srv/www/dev.one.com/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /srv/www/dev.one.com/logs/access.log combined   

</VirtualHost>
```

//////// devone.wsgi ///////////

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/srv/www/dev.one.com/application')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

/////////////

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName dev.two.com/
   ServerAlias www.dev.two.com/
   ServerAdmin andy@two.com

   DocumentRoot /srv/www/dev.two.com/public_html


   <Directory /srv/www/dev.two.com/application>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

   WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/dev.two.com/application/apache/devtwo.wsgi

   Alias /robots.txt /srv/www/dev.two.com/public_html/robots.txt
   Alias /favicon.ico /srv/www/dev.two.com/public_html/favicon.ico
   Alias /media /srv/www/dev.two.com/public_html/media
   Alias /static /srv/www/dev.two.com/public_html/static

   ErrorLog /srv/www/dev.two.com/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /srv/www/dev.two.com/logs/access.log combined   

</VirtualHost>
```

//////// devtwo.wsgi /////

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/srv/www/dev.two.com/application')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

The domains are all hitting my servers IP fine, but they all land on the same page. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Is declared in ports.conf

Comment: Have you used the [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) directive anywhere?

Comment: Yes NameVirtualHost *:80 is declared in ports.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure the vhosts definitions are being loaded in order, from most specific to least specific (ex, possibly by naming them `10_dev.two.com.conf`, `20_dev.one.com.conf`, `30_one.com.conf`)
- The `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives shouldn't have the trailing `/`

Comment: Specifically, when ServerName/ServerAlias don't match correctly, Apache will send all requests to first VirtualHost (default). Good practice to have a first default VirtualHost that has deny from all to catch such problems.